# Secure Transaction between Mobile app and LAMP

Tags: security, transactions, lamp, mobile-devices

I have a Mobile App (iPhone and Android) which allows user to login to his account, change prefs etc...

I want to add a new feature where the user can buy products through his device or upgrade his service. Everything will run from the device and I want to make each transactions the user make it syncs to the web server.

I have HTTPS setup on my server. I would like to know if:

1. It is a good practice? or should I simply tell the user to use our website
2. If "yes", is HTTPS alone good to process these transactions?

Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

yes it's a good practice.

**first of all ALWAYS use HTTPS.**

make sure your certificate is valid and trusted.

for iphone:

- [iPhone: HTTPS client cert authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1460626/iphone-https-client-cert-authentication)
- https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1652697?start=0&tstart=0

for android:

- [Trusting all certificates using HttpClient over HTTPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642777/trusting-all-certificates-using-httpclient-over-https)
- [Accepting a certificate for HTTPs on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2012497/accepting-a-certificate-for-https-on-android)

**second encrypt your data.**

any encryption algorithm or rsa encryption will do the trick.

passing data using GET/POST should not be sent in plain text like: ?user=myuser&pass=mypass. instead use something like ?h28JduDak30fT1pfgmSnShNms762023lflsfdj2h4J. then on your server you simply have to decrypt it using a salt only your phone and the server knows.

example code for iphone:

```
NSString *encrypteddata =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"key=enryptedstring"];
NSData *data = [encrypteddata dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
NSString *datalen = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [data length]];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://yourserver:443/loginscript"]]; //:443 very importantz
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:datalen forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:data];
```

*similar idea for android*

then on your server you can decrypt $_POST['key'] and do your login logic (or others)

here's more resource that will help you:

- [iPhone + sending data from iPhone to server as XML format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2076454/iphone-sending-data-from-iphone-to-server-as-xml-format)
- [iPhone: HTTPS client cert authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1460626/iphone-https-client-cert-authentication)

**note:**
for android you shoud take a look at the HTTPComponents

read more

- http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/cryptography/rsa_encryption.shtml
- http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-programming-tutorials/how-to-receive-data-from-the-server-in-iphone/